# Set WebView2 data folder in WPF/MVVM/Caliburn setup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, webview2, caliburn

We have WPF app which is using Caliburn/MVVM setup.
`ViewModel` registration in `Bootstrapper`:

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomWebViewModel>().As<Screen>();
```

`WebView2` creation in `CustomWebView.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
    <wv2:WebView2 x:Name="WebView2" Source="{Binding WebAddress, Mode=OneWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
</Grid>
```

In developement environment app runs smoothly: `WebView2` shows correct content.
However in production this app is installed in `C:\Program Files\Company\Product\` folder.
When started it throws message:

> Microsoft Edge can't read and write to its data directory: C:\Program
> Files\Company\Product\Product.exe.WebView2\EBWebView

The reason is that WebView2 needs to be configured to use data folder that app would have a permission to use.
This piece of code does it:

```
        var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        var userDataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(appData, "CustomWebView2");

        var task = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, userDataFolder);
        var webView2 = (WebView2)this.FindName("WebView2");
        if (webView2 != null)
            await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(task);
```

Question: where do I call this piece of code in this setup?
I tried `OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` and `OnContentLoading` but in both cases `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` throws:

> System.ArgumentException: '**WebView2 was already initialized with a
> different CoreWebView2Environment**. Check to see if the Source property
> was already set or EnsureCoreWebView2Async was previously called with
> different values.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` before you set the `Source` of the `WebView2` control.

So remove the binding from your XAML markup:

```
<wv2:WebView2 x:Name="WebView2" />
```

...and set it programmatically:

```
var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var userDataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(appData, "CustomWebView2");

var task = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, userDataFolder);
var webView2 = (WebView2)this.FindName("WebView2");
if (webView2 != null)
{
    await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(task);
    webView2.SetBinding(WebView2.SourceProperty, new Binding("WebAddress"));
}
```

Comment: I removed binding from xaml and put your code in `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted`  event handler. But it did not fire!!
It fires only if I put Source binding back to xaml. But in this case it's too late to call `EnsureCoreWebView2Async`.  
So where do I call this code?

Comment: For example in a `Loaded` event handler for the view (`UserControl´) that hosts the `WebView2` control.

Comment: It works in `Loaded` event. Thank you!